# How to look for byte code using grep or other tools?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I know that in my text file i have a character such as

```
"<200f>'n"
```

However I cannot find exactly where it is. I've tried the following

```
grep -E "<200f>"
grep -obUaP "<200f>"
grep -aPo "<200f>"
```

But it won't tell me where it is. How can I grep so I can find `<200f>`. if im correct it's a byte code.

Comment: That absolutely cannot be "a byte" because the value is at least 16 bits, depending on your representation. Do you mean `<` and `>` are notation and the stuff between them is a representation of the code point U+200F (in which encoding?)? Or do you mean the the bytes \x20 and \x0f? Or something else still?

Answer (score 0):

`gawk` (GNU awk) to the rescue:

```
gawk '/\x20\x0f/' input.file
```

Comment: For some reason, it's not finding it either. More I do this more I wonder what <200f> is

Comment: I could only guess as I don't know the use case or the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers! I found the solution. It was a control symbol. And doing

```
grep $'\200' input.txt
```

Solves the problem!